# I can't change work directory with python

Tags: python, pandas, directory

i'm using pandas on python and trying to change work directory with os. the strange fact is that it reads the excel file in the right directory (so it looks like it's working) but when i print the current working directory it tells me that i am still i the old one i was workin in previously.

here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

import os
cwd = os.getcwd()`
bla_bla = os.path.realpath(__file__)
path = r'C:\Users\stain\OneDrive\Desktop\sanofi lavoro 2.0'
os.chdir(path)
print("il file si trova in: ", format(bla_bla))
print("Current working directory: {0}".format(cwd))
print("os.getcwd() returns an object of type: {0}".format(type(cwd)))


#creating dataframe on pandas
df_products = pd.read_excel('DB ALLOCAZIONE PEZZI.xlsx')
print(df_products)
```

and here what i get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQoJa.png)

Comment: If your Excel file and your .py file are in the same directory then this is expected behaviour

Comment: You print `cwd`, which contains the path BEFORE you changed directory; so no wonder it prints the old one! Perhaps you expected it to work like an ALIAS for `os.getcwd()`, but Python doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because you call `os.getcwd()` **before** `os.chdir(path)`. If you want your code to work as you desired you need to do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

import os

bla_bla = os.path.realpath(__file__)
path = r'C:\Users\stain\OneDrive\Desktop\sanofi lavoro 2.0'
os.chdir(path) # Change directory 1st
cwd = os.getcwd() # Get current working directory 2nd
print("il file si trova in: ", format(bla_bla))
print("Current working directory: {0}".format(cwd))
print("os.getcwd() returns an object of type: {0}".format(type(cwd)))


#creating dataframe on pandas
df_products = pd.read_excel('DB ALLOCAZIONE PEZZI.xlsx')
print(df_products)
```